# Flask Testing - How to retrieve variables that were passed to Jinja?

Tags: python, flask

In Flask, how can I test what variables were returned to a Jinja template with `render_template`?

```
@app.route('/foo/'):
def foo():
    return render_template('foo.html', foo='bar')
```

In this example, I want to test that `foo` is equal to `"bar"`.

```
import unittest
from app import app

class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_foo(self):
        with app.test_client() as c:
            r = c.get('/foo/')
            # Prove that the foo variable is equal to "bar"
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done using [signals](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/signals/). I will reproduce the code snippit here:

```py
import unittest
from app import app
from flask import template_rendered
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def captured_templates(app):
    recorded = []
    def record(sender, template, context, **extra):
        recorded.append((template, context))
    template_rendered.connect(record, app)
    try:
        yield recorded
    finally:
        template_rendered.disconnect(record, app)

class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_foo(self):
        with app.test_client() as c:
            with captured_templates(app) as templates:
                r = c.get('/foo/')
                template, context = templates[0]
                self.assertEquals(context['foo'], 'bar')
```

---

Here is another implementation that removes the `template` part and turns it into an iterator.

```py
import unittest
from app import app
from flask import template_rendered
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def get_context_variables(app):
    recorded = []
    def record(sender, template, context, **extra):
        recorded.append(context)
    template_rendered.connect(record, app)
    try:
        yield iter(recorded)
    finally:
        template_rendered.disconnect(record, app)

class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_foo(self):
        with app.test_client() as c:
            with get_context_variables(app) as contexts:
                r = c.get('/foo/')
                context = next(context)
                self.assertEquals(context['foo'], 'bar')
                
                r = c.get('/foo/?foo=bar')
                context = next(context)
                self.assertEquals(context['foo'], 'foo')
                
                # This will raise a StopIteration exception because I haven't rendered
                # and new templates
                next(context)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way will be to use something like that:

```
self.assertTrue('Hello bar!' in r.body)
```

And in `foo.html`:

```
<div>Hello {{ foo }}!</div>
```

Of course I don't know structure of your html, so this example above is just a prototype.

Comment: This would return false positives if the word "bar" was rendered anywhere else in the HTML, even if `foo` was set to something other than "bar"

Comment: Edited. Everything depends of usage. Of course we can use many tricks to get it done, but if we can do it simple, then why not?

Comment: I see your point. The Answer I posted is ugly, 12 lines total, and requires reading the signals documentation to know how it works; whereas yours is a one liner. I suppose I would argue that your answer is coupling the view to the backend unit tests; for example, if you in the future changed "hello" to "hi", then you would have to remember to do it in your tests as well.

Comment: I agree, the question is how many times you have to do this :)